# SQL subqueries with only one date column in output

Tags: mysql, sql

If I am select TV_DATE which is in table TVS, how could I modify this code please?

```
  SELECT TV_DATE, 
        CASE WHEN t5.O_UP BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 5 ELSE O_WT=0 END as O_WT,
        CASE WHEN t5.O_RE BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN  6 ELSE 0 END as O_RD_WT,
        CASE WHEN t5.OR_RD BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END as OR_RD_WT,
        CASE WHEN t5.OR_U_RD BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END as OR_U_RD_WT 


    SELECT TV_DATE, 
        CASE 
            WHEN t5.O_UP BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 5 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS O_WT,
        CASE 
            WHEN t5.O_RE BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 6 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS O_RD_WT,
        CASE 
            WHEN t5.OR_RD BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN 5 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS OR_RD_WT,
        CASE 
            WHEN t5.OR_U_RD BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 3 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS OR_U_RD_WT  
FROM
    (
        SELECT  COALESCE(t1.O_UPDATE,0) AS O_UP, 
                COALESCE(t2.O_READ,0) AS O_RE, 
                COALESCE(t3.OR_READ,0) AS OR_RD, 
                COALESCE(t4.OR_U_READ,0) AS OR_U_RD 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as O_UPDATE from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='U' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'we%avd%'
        ) t1,
        (
            SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as O_READ from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='X' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'er%dfr%'
        ) t2,
        (
            SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as OR_READ from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='X' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'cv%dfr%' AND TV_I_NAME NOT LIKE 'dsf%er%'
        ) t3,
        (
            SELECT SUM(TV_R_U_COUNT) as OR_U_READ from TVS where TV_T_NAME='abcd' AND TV_DATE between '2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' AND TV_R_U='X' AND TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'ad%asd%ere'
        ) t4
    ) t5,
     TVS
```

Could I request some help to figure this out please?

I'm looking to get an output of the below kind.

```
+-------------+------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
|    DATE     | O_WT | O_RD_WT | OR_RD_WT | OR_U_RD_WT | OR_U_RD_WT |
+-------------+------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| 2015-01-01  |    5 |       6 |        4 |          3 |          0 |
| 2015-01-02  |    5 |       0 |        0 |          3 |          0 |
| 2015-01-03  |    5 |       0 |        0 |          0 |          0 |
| 2015-01-04  |    5 |       6 |        4 |          0 |          0 |
| 2015-01-05  |    5 |       0 |        0 |          3 |          0 |
+-------------+------+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I tried UNION between the SELECT statements but it messes the output. The output is definitely wrong. Can't think of how to get this working :-(

Comment: For one thing, the conditions like this: **`TV_I_NAME LIKE 'w1%we%' AND TV_I_NAME like 'we%avd%'`** are guaranteed to never be true. If one of those conditions is TRUE, the other is guaranteed to be FALSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that repetition of the predicates in the individual inline views (t1, t2, t3, t4), and given that you want to return the "counts" on the same row, I would use a single query against the `tvs` table, and use "conditional aggregation".

I'd use an expression that has conditional test, and returns the `tv_r_u_count` only when that condition is true, and wrap that in an aggregate function. For example:

```
SUM(IF(tv_r_u = 'U' AND t.tv_i_name LIKE 'we%avd%', tv_r_u_count, NULL))
```

It looks like you are also wanting to do a conditional test on the result from that... if it's between 1 and 3 then return 5.

The question you asked, how to return `tv_date`. It looks like you want to generate the sum of the counts based for each `tv_date`. To get that, we'd add a `GROUP BY tv_date` to the query, and return `tv_date` in the `SELECT` list.

As I noted in my comment on your question, some of the predicates in your query are mutually exclusive. That is, if

```
 foo LIKE 'w1%we%'
```

evaluates to TRUE, we know that

```
 foo LIKE 'we%avd%'
```

is going to return FALSE. When combined with an `AND`, i.e. TRUE `AND` FALSE will never return TRUE. (I expect that you meant at least one of those conditions to include an additional wildcard, like a leading `%` character, so there's a possibility for the AND'ed conditions to return TRUE.

I would generate the specified result using a query something like the one below.

I've purposefully indented, to make the closing paren `)` for the `SUM(` "line up" in the same column. I've indented similarly for the `CASE` expressions to line up. The blank lines aren't necessary, but I did that to highlight the conditional test, the part that changes between the expressions, the rest of the expression is repeated (except for the alias assigned to the column.)

```
 SELECT t.date
      , CASE WHEN
          SUM(
            CASE WHEN

              t.tv_r_u = 'U' AND t.tv_i_name LIKE 'we%avd%'

            THEN t.tv_r_u_count END
          ) BETWEEN  1 AND  3 THEN 5 ELSE 0
        END AS o_wt
      , CASE WHEN
          SUM(
            CASE WHEN

              t.tv_r_u = 'X' AND t.tv_i_name LIKE 'er%dfr%'

            THEN t.tv_r_u_count END
          ) BETWEEN  3 AND  5 THEN 6 ELSE 0
        END AS o_rd_wt
      , CASE WHEN
          SUM(
            CASE WHEN

              t.tv_r_u = 'X' AND t.tv_i_name LIKE 'cv%dfr%' AND t.tv_i_name NOT LIKE 'dsf%er%'

            THEN t.tv_r_u_count END
          ) BETWEEN  5 AND 10 THEN 5 ELSE 0
        END AS or_rd_wt
      , CASE WHEN
          SUM(
            CASE WHEN

              t.tv_r_u = 'X' AND t.tv_i_name LIKE 'ad%asd%ere'

            THEN t.tv_r_u_count END
          ) BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN 3 ELSE 0
        END AS or_u_rd_wt
   FROM tvs t
  WHERE t.tv_t_name = 'abcd'
    AND t.tv_date   BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-07-01'
    AND t.tv_r_u    IN ('U','X')
    AND t.tv_i_name LIKE 'w1%we%'
  GROUP BY t.date
```

Note that some of the predicates in the `WHERE` clause could be repeated (or moved) to the conditional tests in the SUM() aggregates.  For example, we could remove the line:

```
    AND t.tv_r_u    IN ('U','X')
```

and get an equivalent result, since the conditions in the aggregates are already checking `tv_r_u='U'` or `tv_r_u='X'`.

The difference would be we might get more rows returned, if the removal of that predicate in the WHERE clause includes more rows, iwth other values of `tv_r_u` that have additional `tv_date` values that don't appear on `'U'` or `'X'` rows.

Note that the only `tv_date` values that will be returned are values from rows that satisfy *all* of the predicates in the `WHERE` clause.

As another example, we could repeat the conditional test

```
  AND t.tv_t_name = 'abcd'
```

in each of the expressions in the SELECT list, and then (optionally) remove it from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hello Spencer - My heartfelt thanks to you for such a good explanation & refined query. I'll give this a crack & let you know. Thank you  again.

Comment: @user3124689: The expressions in the SELECT list are a bit involved. I'd probably test first with just the SUM() (removing that outermost CASE). What kind of gets lost in all that jumble is the "conditional aggregation"... a single pass through the `tvs` table, GROUP BY `date`, and an aggregate function (e.g. SUM or COUNT) on the collapsed rows. The "trick" is the expression inside the aggregate... a conditional test. It's a useful (and familiar) pattern for report-type queries the "get counts of..." or "get totals for..." with multiple conditions.

Comment: Hello  Spencer - Am trying out the query. I now have multiple ranges to test against such as BETWEEN 101 AND 1000  THEN 1,BETWEEN 1001 AND 10000  THEN 3, > 10000  THEN 5. I included them one below the other after the BETWEEN condition that is already there. However I get a syntax error. Ho could I include these? Could you please help?

Comment: I worked it out Spencer. I repeated the "WHEN SUM" block for each of the conditions. I'd like to say a big big thank you to you again. :)

Comment: @user3124689: If I had to check the value of the `SUM()` expression multiple times, I'd avoid repeating that whole expression. I'd likely return the SUM() expressions in an inline view (i.e. remove the outermost CASE, to have a query return the SUM(). Then reference that query in the FROM clause of an outer query, like you were doing in the original query. (My objective in doing that would be to avoid repeating the same SUM() expression multiple times.)

Comment: Hello Spencer - I've requested for help on this question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230671/mysql-difference-between-the-type-of-queries . I've tried rewriting another query of mine following the guidelines here. Could you pleSe check ?